# Refresh UIButton text with fade animation

Tags: swift, xcode, animation, uibutton

I'm trying to implement a simple QRScanner app that presents a button, if a QR code is scanned. Now I want to present the same button for multiple QR codes, but in case two QR codes are scanned  one after the other, and both codes present the same button, I want to shortly refresh the button text with a fade animation in order to indicate that a new QR code has been scanned. I noticed that if you change the button title, that animation is triggered but if you set it to a string identical to its current title, it doesn't show any animation anymore. I was wondering if there's a simple way to trigger that same animation even if I don't want to change the title's value. Here's my code excerpt:

```
func setValidMessageLabel() {
    messageLabel.backgroundColor = color
    messageLabel.setTitle("Check Now", for: .normal)
    messageLabel.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
}

func  setInvalidMessageLabel() {
    messageLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0.7, alpha: 0.6)
    messageLabel.setTitle("Invalid Code", for: .normal)
    messageLabel.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
}

if metadataObj.stringValue != nil && metadataObj.stringValue != key {
    key = metadataObj.stringValue
    messageLabel.isEnabled = true

switch key {
            case cokeWin:
                setValidMessageLabel()
            case cokeLose:
                setValidMessageLabel()
            default:
                setInvalidMessageLabel()
                return
            }
}
```

Happy for any help :)

Comment: where you are animating ?

Comment: really not animating, I just wanted to have that same fade out and in effect I get when I change the titles string value. My workaround until now was setting the title to "Check Now" for one case and " Check Now " for the other one. Notice the spaces left and right of the second Check Now. The differing string values triggered that fade effect~